# Oracle connection is not working- ORA-01882: timezone region not found (All Db applications and IDE)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlconnection, dbconnection

[image]
Im new to ubuntu and have taken youtube reference to install oracle 10g in to the system.
And succesfully done it.
Later , tried connecting to database from dbeaver and sql developer applications.Both are showing the same error.Tried from eclipse ide, having the same error.
But , the local host link of oracle 10g(http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/) is working , im able to run the commands there.

Comment: What is your operating system time zone set to? You might need to change that, or override it anyway in the application config (e.g. Java settings via command-line flags). And why such an old version of Oracle - you might be seeing a driver problem?

Comment: Thanks , tried all ways but did not solve.
Adding below property to application properties solved in spring suite ide.
`spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false`

And in Dbeaver : Solution

**Go to DBeaver install directory C:\Program Files\DBeaver
Open dbeaver.ini
After the -vmargs line, add this: -Duser.timezone=UTC
Save file and restart DBeaver**